# Access of undefined property AS3, i dont understand

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok, so I'm watching this tutorial: http://as3gametuts.com/2012/01/08/platformer-3/ and when

For some reason this code won't work:

```
xSpeed -= scrollY;
ySpeed -= scrollX;

back.x = scrollX;
back.y = scrollY;
```

And calls for

1120: Access of undefined property scrollX
1120: Access of undefined property scrollY

Comment: I tried to changeout the code back and forth, so this is the original:
   
    scrollX -= xSpeed;
    scrollY -= ySpeed;

    back.x = scrollX;
    back.y = scrollY;

Comment: Sorry, not going to go follow that tutorial to get the rest of the context for this code. You might want to show some more detail. The error means that you're trying to set a property on an object, but that object does not define such a property. The code you've posted here is not enough to provide an answer. Specifically, we need to know what the class is that this code appears in, and potentially what class it might extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the vars scrollX and scrollY to your code?  In the source they're declared right above xSpeed around line 16.

Comment: Yeah, i would love to, if i only knew how :P